# Howto forward traffic between multiple OpenVPNs

Tags: networking, centos, openvpn, nat

I have an OpenVPN server which hosts two VPN networks, one is bridged and the other one is routed. See the following draft:
[image]

The VPNs are working quite well while they are used in isolation.

But if I'm logged in on host3 and I try to get a connection (ping for example) to 192.168.178.1 (host2) this doesn't work.
192.168.178.10 (host1) works.

However beeing on host1, 192.168.178.1 is reachable.

Host1 is a CentosOS 6.5 machine and has ip forwarding enabled:

```
[root@gw-1 ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
[root@gw-1 ~]#
```

Any ideas? Do I need some masquerading is this setup?

Comment: How do the routing tables look like? Does host2 know it has to send packets to 10.1.0.0/24 (?) through the tunnel?

Comment: What is the OpenVPN configuration?

Comment: Is there one openvpn server process running on host1? You need to know that in that case forwarding between openvpn clients happens inside the openvpn server process, and not in the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the question of @enno-gröper gave me a hint. Of course host2 doesn't know anything about 10.1.0.0/24. 
So I tried it with masquerading all traffic from 10.1.0.0/24 to 192.168.178.0/24 through tap0 on the OpenVPN server and it worked.